# Cannot set Allow quoted newlines property in bigquery using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-bigquery, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I cannot able to enable property "Allow quoted newlines" in google bigquery load job.

```
configuration = {
        'load': {
            'createDisposition': create_disposition,
            'destinationTable': {
                'projectId': destination_project,
                'datasetId': destination_dataset,
                'tableId': destination_table,
            },
            'schema': {
                'fields': schema_fields
            },
            'sourceFormat': source_format,
            'sourceUris': source_uris,
            'writeDisposition': write_disposition,
            'allowJaggedRows': True,
            'allowQuotedNewlines': True,
            'ignoreUnknownValues': True
        }
    }

    if source_format == 'CSV':
        configuration['load']['skipLeadingRows'] = skip_leading_rows
        configuration['load']['fieldDelimiter'] = field_delimiter
        configuration['load']['encoding'] = 'UTF-8'
        configuration['load']['quote'] = ''

jobs = self.service.jobs()
        job_data = {
            'configuration': configuration
        }
query_reply = jobs \
            .insert(projectId=self.project_id, body=job_data) \
            .execute()
        job_id = query_reply['jobReference']['jobId']
        job = jobs.get(projectId=self.project_id, jobId=job_id).execute()
```

But property *'allowQuotedNewlines': True* is not working.  When I inspected using bigquery UI(web view), this property is not checked.

[image]

Did I miss something? what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else coming across this issue, the above syntax is for JSON scripts interacting with the API.

For Python `bigquery.LoadJobConfig()`, use `allow_quoted_newlines` to get the `Job` to load properly with quoted newlines in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the row
configuration['load']['quote'] = ''

If you want to allow quoted newlines, you have to specify a non-empty quote char.